# Creating sandbox test payments in Shopify with PayPal?

Tags: paypal, shopify

Is there a way to test paypal transactions in shopify development?

I have tried adding sandbox emails but it keeps giving me `Some of your info isn't correct. Please try again.` --- I have updated the passwords to ensure everything is correct.  I assume Shopify is not allowing this?

Is there a way to integrate paypal sandbox?

It's important that it is PayPal and not credit cards in general.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Really not trying to use real money for a few simple tests as it seems Shopify is suggesting here: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/payments/paypal/set-up-paypal#testing-paypal

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem Shopify offers the option to turn on sandbox mode, probably because it's unnecessary and confusing for most of their users.

Shopify has already done all the integration with PayPal, there is no need to test anything repeatedly. Just make sure it's working before launch.

Comment: I am resorting to wasting a couple dollars to integrate a feature.  Seems a bit odd that wouldn't simply have it there to allow.  The dev team seems to have made some odd choices when it comes to developing so this isn't too surprising.

Comment: It's pretty amazing to think you can't integrate with the PayPal sandbox. Shopify may have already done the integration work, but that doesn't mean we don't want to test it in dev and QA. Also, Shopify allows you to use test mode with the Stripe integration, so why not with PayPal as well?